# Passing --node-args --inspect to pm2 with process file

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm currently using `pm2` with a process file as such:

`pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`

I would like to pass in the `--inspect` flag in order to start the node inspector. However, doing this doesn't work:

`pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --node-args="--inspect"`

This page http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#considerations mentions

> All command line options passed when using the JSON app declaration will be dropped i.e.

Is this the reason that this isn't working. Does anyone know why?

Is there a way to pass in the the `--inspect` flag without adding it to the process file? I'm aware that adding the `node_args` property to the process file work. I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to get CLI option to work.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#start-an-app) you should be able to do this:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js -- --inspect
```

Quoting:

> Pass extra arguments to the script
>
> -- arg1 arg2 arg3

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a config file, you can also add directly to the file via `interpreter_args` or `node_args`, like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'app1',
    script: './app.js',
    interpreter_args: '--inspect'
  }]
}
```

See the [docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#general) for more info.

**Bonus:** if you want to inspect multiple processes at once, you can just specify different ports:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'app1',
      script: './app1.js',
      interpreter_args: '--inspect=9229',
    },
    {
      name: 'app2',
      script: './app2.js',
      interpreter_args: '--inspect=9230',
    },
  ],
};
```